# How to implement Stack Overflow textarea that will restore your typing when asking a question after you close and reopen it

Tags: javascript, html

Implement it with HTML5 storage? Constantly upload to server session?

Which is a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 storage? Yes you can, but it won't be supported by old browsers. Another ways of doing that are:

1. Store draft into cookies every n seconds.
2. Store draft at server side using ajax requests every n seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use one of these frameworks:

- [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557)
- [Sammy](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.6.3/all#Sammy.Storage)
- and many others (a quick search in github and google code should give you other anwsers)

They provide a persistent storage API in the browser, with various implementations/fallback dependening on the browser (cookie, localStorage, jquery data, adobe flash, google gears...)